# aws CLI configured properly but why boto3 not getting the credential?

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, boto3

AWS cli working but boto3 not working. I installed aws CLI on my ubuntu server and the problem is boto3 not getting the credentials from my Ubuntu machine until I hardcode the key in my code like

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', 
                      aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY, 
                      aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY, 
                      region_name=REGION_NAME
                      )
```

I also run this command to `aws s3 ls`  to verify does aws CLI working or not and it's returning all of my aws bucket name which means CLI configured properly but why boto3 not getting the credential from my ubuntu machine. I am using boto3 in my django project.

Comment: What is `settings`? Where is the `settings` object coming from? If you just changed the entire code to `s3_client = boto3.client('s3')` then Boto3 would use the defaults (the same values `aws s3 ls` is using).

Comment: _boto3 not working_ What exactly do you mean "not working"?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @John Gordon I was getting error which was bot3 credential error which means boto3 couldn't get   the secret key and access key from CLI.

Comment: @Mark B in my django settings.py I have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',default='')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',default='')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME',default='')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = config('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN',default='')` if I remove the first two line it's not working on my ubuntu server but also working same settings  without first two line on my local pc.

Answer (score 0):

As I am using gunicorn on my Linux server to run my Dajngo app so gunicorn was not getting the aws key from the environment variable until I set it manually in my gunicorn.service file like:

```
[Service]
Environment=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='my key'
Environment=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='my secrect'
```